# Explain this Python program

Tags: python, recursion

```
def hanoi(n, A, C, B):
    def print_move(A, C):
        print(A, '-->', C)

    if n == 1:
        print_move(A, C)

    else:
        hanoi(n-1, A, B, C)
        hanoi(1, A, C, B)
        hanoi(n-1, B, C, A)
```

This is a program that solves the towers of hanoi problem, however I don't understand it at all.

1. When will the program end?
2. When n-1 gets to 1 shouldn't it get stuck in infinite loop because of the condition?
3. The program will work as intended until hanoi(1, A, C, B), because of the condition it will print A --> B, but shouldn't it print A --> C?
4. Can any of the recursive functions affect others (hanoi2 sets n to 1, but will hanoi3 also use 1 or n-1?) and which lines will execute in order?

Comment: #1: this is definitely something you can figure out on your own by running the program.  #2: no.  why do you think this is the case?  #3: why do you think it'll print A --> B.  it seems to me it prints A --> C.  #4: all the lines will execute in order.  hanoi3 will use `n-1`, as shown.

Comment: About #3, hanoi1 will execute until it hits 1 and after that it will print A --> C, then hanoi2 should print A --> B (and it will), do you understand now why I think it will print A --> B?

Comment: Consider using something like http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to work through this yourself.

Comment: @SMALLname you need to tag me (with @dbliss) to get me to see your messages.  no, i don't understand why you think that.  hanoi2 is `hanoi(1, A, C, B)`.  this results in `print(A, '-->', C)` where `A` is `A` and `C` is `C`.

Answer (score 0):

The program will end when `n == 1` because at that time it will use this case:

```
if n == 1:
    print_move(A, C)
```

and NOT this case:

```
else:
    hanoi(n-1, A, B, C)
    hanoi(1, A, C, B)
    hanoi(n-1, B, C, A)
```

More formally we know it will eventually reach `n == 1` because `n` is strictly moving towards that case in every recursive call. The `n` variable is therefore a [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant) for this recursion.

Comment: Something will be printed only when n == 1, however there are 3 recursive calls so there should be only 3 answers, right?Well, the program will print all the solutions, how do you explain that?

Comment: Each non-terminating recursive call will make three new recursive calls. Like the [hydra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra) in Greek mythology.

Answer (score -1):

This is the recursive algorithm to solve the towers of hanoi problem.

[read more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive%5Fsolution)

Comment: i don't know that this qualifies as a real answer.  you might as well have posted "google it."